# Is it possible that $f_X(x)\:f_Y(y) = g(x)\:h(y)$ where $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are valid PDFs and $g$ and $h$ are not valid PDFs?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that the joint PDF $f_{X,Y}$ of X and Y factors into the marginal PDFs of $X$ and $Y$ $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x)\:f_{Y}(y)$. Then is it possible for $f_{X,Y}$ to **also** factor as $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = g(x)\:h(y)$ where $g$ and $h$ are nonnegative functions and are not valid PDFs?

Comment: Put minus signs in front of each.

Comment: I edited to make $g$ and $h$ nonnegative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Take $g = \dfrac 1 \lambda f_X(x), h = \lambda f_Y(y)$, for some constant $\lambda > 0$ (other than $\lambda = 1$, of course).

Comment: @DilipSarwate But then $h$ would not be a function of $y$ alone.

Comment: @leonbloy You are right; I am deleting my comment and editing GFauxpa's answer.

Comment: ...And taking $(g(x),h(y))=(cf_X(x),c^{-1}f_Y(y))$ for some $c\gt0$ is the ONLY option.